# how to receive shadows using ShaderMaterial in THREE.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have ran a simple code , which creates a shader material and assign it to my object , I know that the code is missing the shadow part "but simply I don't know how to make this part!! "

here is the function which creates the material:

```
function createShaderMaterial( id, light, ambientLight ) {

var shader = THREE.ShaderTypes[ id ];

var u = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );

var vs = shader.vertexShader;
var fs = shader.fragmentShader;

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { uniforms: u, vertexShader: vs, fragmentShader: fs } );

material.uniforms.uDirLightPos.value = light.position;
material.uniforms.uDirLightColor.value = light.color;
material.uniforms.uSpecularColor.value.copy( new THREE.Color(0.8,0.8,0.8) );
material.uniforms.shininess = 100;

material.uniforms.uAmbientLightColor.value = ambientLight.color;

return material;

}
```

and in the calling it is:

```
var materialColor = new THREE.Color();
materialColor.setRGB( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
gouraudMaterial = createShaderMaterial( "gouraud", light, ambientLight );
gouraudMaterial.uniforms.uMaterialColor.value.copy( materialColor );
```

and assigning that material to any object , after some tests I have found that it can cast shadows "on any other material like phong material" , but it doesn't receive shadows :S

edit1:

well it raises an error:
[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2

here is the material function:

```
function createShaderMaterial2() {
var ambient = 0x050505, diffuse = 0x331100, specular = 0xffffff, shininess = 10, scale = 23;

// normal map shader

var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normalmap" ];
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );

uniforms[ "enableAO" ].value = false;
uniforms[ "enableDiffuse" ].value = false;
uniforms[ "enableSpecular" ].value = false;
uniforms[ "enableReflection" ].value = false;
uniforms[ "enableDisplacement" ].value = false;

//uniforms[ "tNormal" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/normal/ninja/normal.jpg" );
//uniforms[ "tAO" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/normal/ninja/ao.jpg" );

//uniforms[ "tDisplacement" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/normal/ninja/displacement.jpg" );
//uniforms[ "uDisplacementBias" ].value = - 0.428408;
//uniforms[ "uDisplacementScale" ].value = 2.436143;

//uniforms[ "uNormalScale" ].value.y = -1;

uniforms[ "uDiffuseColor" ].value.setHex( diffuse );
uniforms[ "uSpecularColor" ].value.setHex( specular );
uniforms[ "uAmbientColor" ].value.setHex( ambient );

uniforms[ "uShininess" ].value = shininess;

//uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = reflectionCube;
uniforms[ "uReflectivity" ].value = 0.1;

uniforms[ "uDiffuseColor" ].value.convertGammaToLinear();
uniforms[ "uSpecularColor" ].value.convertGammaToLinear();
uniforms[ "uAmbientColor" ].value.convertGammaToLinear();


var parameters = { fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: shader.vertexShader, uniforms: uniforms, lights: true, fog: false };
var material1 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( parameters );

return material1;}
```

Comment: What is `THREE.ShaderTypes`?

Comment: the example which I took this snippet from contains a list of material types ""like phong , lambert ..."" they are passed as a string to this list

Comment: Did you look at the three.js examples, like this one: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_normalmap.html?

Comment: well thanks for the link , it showed me more , but still there is 2 main problems that I encountered:

when THREE.ShaderLib is phong , the material appeared black
and in this example "normalmap" it generates this error

Comment: also another note , when it is shader to "phong" and I apply a color into diffuse , it completely becomes transparent "it casts shadows,but not visible at all"

Comment: I would suggest that you learn from the three.js examples, instead.

Comment: I have edited the post , check it out

Comment: well for now the 'phong' shader has worked after some testing , but the main issue is: shadows looks jaggy , I did all this to fix "low quality" shadows without tesselation "wanted it to calculate per pixel" , the shadows quality is set for each light to 4k * 4k

Comment: If you have a new issue, you need to make a new post. Show a live example -- jsfiddle, for example.

Comment: ok thanks :) , here is the new post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861552/making-good-looking-shadows-in-fragment-shader-in-three-js